# How to perform Autocomplete on json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object as follows:

```
var subaccounts = [
{
    "name": "account 12200002 inc",
    "id": "3e55979f46304334b1de3b17fe0942d7",
    "billingContactInfo": {
      "country": "USA",
      "email": "pooja687236.wagh@neustar.biz",
      "firstName": "poojas",
      "lastName": "wagh",
       "address1": "1234 asdf",
        "address2": "",
         "city": "mountain view",
         "phone": "",
         "postalCode": "95035",
         "stateOrProvince": "CA",
         "fax": ""
   }
```

}
]

For autocomplete i tried this:

```
selectedSubAccount = _.each(subaccounts, function(account) { 
                            return account.name
                        }); // to get the account name in the input field
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                        source: selectedSubAccount[0].name
                        
                        });
```

Below is the html:

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder = "search">
```

However when i type into the input field, it gives me this error:

```
GET http://home.stagingwpm.neustar.biz/account%2012200002%20inc?term=a 404 (Not Found)
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way to do the autocomplete:
Anyone for any ideas? Please and thanks!

EDIT:::::

My selectedSubAccount gives me the following o/p.

[image]

so my "name" and "id" fields are below the "billingContactInfo". how can i make it an array containing only names for me to use`source: selectedSubAccount`: ?

Thanks

Comment: Just do `source: selectedSubAccount` since the array should only contain the names in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Autocomplete Widget API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> ***String:* When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data.** It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the `source` option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types `foo`, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

In your example the source is of the type string, and therefore it expects it to be a URL to return the JSON. Your variable `selectedSubAccount` should however be an array consisting only of the names (you assign it in your `_.each`-loop) and should therefore be a valid source. So try to use the following source instead:

```
source: selectedSubAccount
```

Comment: im getting an array of objects(shown in my edit part). Im not sure the  for each loop isn't returning only the "name" fields from the object..ay ideas how can i achieve this?